# How to optimize throughput when sending to EventHubs with .Net core app

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

How can I create multiple EventHubClients that use multiple underlying TCP connects to allow fast writes to the EventHubs from a .net core web app?

In the programming guide for EventHubs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide) it is written:

> It is important to note that additional EventHubClient objects created from a messaging factory instance reuse the same underlying TCP connection. Therefore, these objects have a client-side limit on throughput. The Create method reuses a single messaging factory. If you need very high throughput from a single sender, then you can create multiple message factories and one EventHubClient object from each messaging factory.

And then they have a code sample:

```
var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("your_connection_string");
var client = factory.CreateEventHubClient("MyEventHub");
```

However, I dont know where / if there is a MessagingFactory in .Net core? Is it at all possible to do this from .Net core? I looked at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus but could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

After testing it seems like creating multiple clients with `EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString` will open multiple connections to EventHubs just as expected. (The connections can be seen as separate TCP connections in Windows Resource Monitor).

(When I reread the documentation carefully I think its only applies to EventHubClients created from a MessaginFactory, which was not clear the first time I read it. But I add this as an answer and let the question stay in case someone else reads the documentation like I did at first)

Comment: MessagingFactory is not available in the Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs library. Do you know if there is an alternate way I can try to reuse the underlying TCP connection when creating eventhub client since it is not available ? –

Comment: Not that I know of.